# divisibility proof verification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

practicing proofs for an upcoming exam, can someone please verify?

Prove that $\forall d,n\in \mathbb{N}$ if $d^2\nmid n^2 $, $d\nmid n $

proof by contradiction:

$\exists d,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d^2\nmid n^2$ and $d\mid n$

suppose $d\mid n$ then there exists an integer $c$ such that $n=dc$

now if $n=dc$ then $n^2 = (dc)^2$

$n^2 = (dc)^2 = d \cdot d \cdot c \cdot c = d^2 \cdot c^2$

which is a contradiction and hence if $d \mid n $ then $d^2 \mid n^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good. More concisely, just prove by contraposition.

> Suppose that $d \mid n$. Then there is some $c \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n = dc$. So $n^2 = (dc)^2 = d^2\underbrace{(c^2)}_{\in \mathbb Z}$ and hence $d^2 \mid n^2$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: awesome, thanks!